# Justification for this Calculus "Shortcut" (Logarithm of Derivatives)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

In school, we were shown a "shortcut" (I am not sure if this "shortcut" even has a name) in calculus that describes the relationship between the derivatives of a function, but we were never shown why this is true.

Consider:

- Let $f(x)$ be some function
- Let $g(x)$ be the derivative of $f(x)$
- Let $h(x) = g(x)/f(x)$
- Shortcut: Then,
  $$ h(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log f(x) $$

I have always been confused about this – does anyone know how we can be sure that this shortcut is mathematically valid, and if this shortcut has a specific name?

Thank you!

Comment: It's just the chain rule in reverse: try taking $\frac{d}{dx} \log(f(x)).$

Comment: There is no need to introduce the notation $g(x)$  Just say: "$f(x)$ is a function and $h(x) = f'(x)/f(x)$. Then $h(x) = (d/dx)(\log f(x))$." I find that easier to read. Or get rid of the notation $h(x)$ too: "if $f(x)$ is a function then $f'(x)/f(x) = (d/dx)(\log f(x))$."

Comment: I would guess you were shown this "shortcut" in a specific context where it solved a certain kind of problem. The fact that $f'(x)/f(x) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log(f(x))$ is simply how you would typically differentiate $\log(f(x))$, so what makes this interesting is how you use it in whatever context you saw it in.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments! Reading your comments, it makes me realize I am probably overthinking all of this, and this "shortcut" just comes from the basic laws of derivatives?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. It greatly helps the question visible to various search engines and hence is crucial for maintaining this community as a repository of mathematical knowledge. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The shortcut you might have seen is called *logarithmic differentiation*: Sometimes, with functions like $f(x) = e^{x^2}(1+x^3)^{-1/2}(\cos^2 x)$, it is easier to take $\log f(x)$ and then differentiate.